# c# nested data tables/sets to n-number levels

Tags: c#, recursion, dataset, master-detail, datarow

I would like to build a relationship such as modeled below using datatables or datasets which are linked together.

Given a nested bill of materials/Model:

> A. Make Item (A) comprises of (this is the base level/ a child of children)
>
> > 1. purchased item (aa)
> > 2. purchased item (bb)
> > 3. purchased item (cc)
>
> B. Make Item (B) comprises of  (this is a parent to (A), and a child to (C))
>
> > 1. purchased item (dd)
> > 2. make item (A)
>
> C. Make Item (C) comprises of (this is a parent to (B), and a parent-parent (A))
>
> > 1. Make Item (B)

In this example the hierarchy is 3 elements deep. At the top level, the parent of make item (C) -> Make Item (B) -> Make Item (A) which is made up of purchased items with no children.

My goal is to create a Datatable or Dataset with these relationships.  I created a method to iterate through a level's elements and if it contains a make item, to call itself again passing in the make item as the parent.  For example:

```
.
.
.
//iterate through parent, if child-element is make then get the bill of materials for the child.
  DataTable CurLevelBOM; //has the current level bill of materials (C) above
  DataSet Children = new DataSet();


  foreach(DataRow BOMrow in CurLevelBOM){
   if (BOMRow["Make"].ToString() = "Y"){

      //Get the Bill of materials for this element
      Children.Tables.Add(this.getChild(BOMrow).tables.thisLevelBom);  
    }
  }
.
.
.
private DataSet getChild(DataRow ChildMakeItem){
   DataSet DataSetToReturn = new DataSet();
   DataSet Child = new DataSet();
   DataTable thisLevelBom = BomTableAdapter.getdata(ChildMakeItem["Item"].ToString();

   foreach(DataRow row in thisLevelBom){
      if(row["Make"].ToString() == "Y"){
         Child = getChild(row);
         DataSetToReturn.Tables.Add(Child.Tables.thisLevelBom);  //add this bom to 
      } else {
       /// this row is not a make item and shouldn't get children
      }
  }
}
```

I'm stuck - I'm not sure if a DataSet can have many version of the same table - in this case a bill of materials.  Nor am I aware of a way to set the relationships between the (B) item to (A) item using (C) objects.

OR, if you have a different approach, I'm all ears :)  TYIA.

Comment: what is the relationship between a 'MakeItem' and a 'PurchasedItem'. One to many, or many to many?

Comment: the relationship is many purchased to one make item